# Java play framework Async operation on same object

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, playframework

I'm trying to perform Async operations on the same object for example I would pass List to Promise to perform concurrently 3 queries where each query when finishes adds queried results to the List and finally the http result returns the Full list when all concurrent queries results finish.

Having a look at this tutorial:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync

I could make something like this

```
    return async(
            promise(new Function0<Integer>() {
                public Integer apply() {
                    firstQuery();
                }
            })
            . promise(new Function0<Integer>() {
                public Integer apply() {
                    return secondQuery();
                }
            })

            .map(new Function<Integer,Result>() {
                public Result apply(Integer i) {
                    Logger.debug("we have got "+i);
                return ok("Got " + i);
                }
            })     
        );
```

to make 2 operations work concurrently , but neither I could pass an object to promise and neither I can get the result of both queries to handle both results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Promise.sequence](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#sequence(play.libs.F.Promise...)) to achieve that

```
F.Promise<Integer> one, two;
one = F.Promise.promise(new F.Function0<Integer>() {
    @Override public Integer apply() throws Throwable {
        return 20;
    }
});
two = F.Promise.promise(new F.Function0<Integer>() {
    @Override public Integer apply() throws Throwable {
        return 22;
    }
});
return F.Promise.sequence(one, two).map(new F.Function<List<Integer>, Result>() {
    @Override
    public Result apply(List<Integer> integers) throws Throwable {
        int res = integers.get(0) + integers.get(1);
        return ok("The answer is " + res);
    }
});
```

Comment: If it performs DB queries, it's better to use public static <A> F.Promise<java.util.List<A>> sequence(scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext ec,
                                        F.Promise<A>... promises)>> Otherwise he blocks the threads designated for request handling.